# Python UDP Message not broadcasting on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, udp

when I run the following python on a windows 10 machine the udp message is sent to all devices on the network correctly.  However when I run it on a linux machine (the raspberry pi) the message does not broadcast out.  When if run "ifconfig" i can see the broadcast is up and is "192.168.2.255".  On linux microcomputer I have to set UDP_PORT to the device ip "192.168.2.124".  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class wroom(Thread):
def run(self):
    UDP_PORT_NO = 6789
    UDP_IP = '192.168.2.255'
    while 1:
        try:
            clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            while 1:
                time.sleep(2)
                clientSock.sendto('test'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT_NO))

        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Remove the try/except and you'll see the error.

Comment: Sorry I deleted a print statement at the end of the while loop print 'here' thar runs and the except had             except Exception as e:
                try:
                        print str(e)
                except:
                    pass
which did not print any exception.  Its not actually throwing an exception.  its something to do with linux or the raspberry pi that is preventing the broadcast on 192.196.2.255.   I will continue to search.  Thank you for the reply

Comment: You want the full traceback. Just remove the try/except.

Comment: FYI - https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/

Comment: clientSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1) above the while loop solved the issue.  Thank you for your help, and reply.  uch appreciated.